# Check radio buttons from dynamic form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've created a form on which I load several questions from a database, the questions are loaded by category on different pages, now that I have that I wan't to check that all of the radiobuttons have a value that is they should not be null (unchecked state).

So if Radio buttons are all checked then I can proceed to the next page with the next category of questions:

**Q)** How how can I check radio button state since questions are loaded from database and in a future in Y category can be N numbers of questions.

Comment: So you're dynamically generating radio buttons from the database, and you want to make sure that each radio button has a value? And if it doesn't have a value, what should happen?

Comment: if it doesn't have a value then the user can't go to the next page

Comment: Instead of creating the radio buttons dynamically, have you considered using a `RadioButtonList` instead, and binding it to your result set?

Comment: but if I do that, it will work with several questions/radios with different controls? It's just that I allready have the web loading all of the questions, and the pagination working, the only thing that is missing is the validation on each page.

Comment: @Carlos have you tried using validation controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're generating the radio buttons dynamically and want to verify that they all have values, you should wrap in a container like a `Panel` or a `PlaceHolder`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <!-- put the dynamically generated radio buttons here -->
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

By putting them in a container, you can then do something like this:

```
foreach (RadioButton radio in PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    //set the enabled state based on whether a value is assigned
    radio.Enabled = radio.Value.Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, but the thing that is missing now is that it grabs each radio by itself, not by groups. So if I have 3 radios for the same question it's obvious that only 1 can be selected, but this function will take 1 as selected and the other 2 as no selected, so it will never let me go to the next page

Comment: Thanks, I've allready figured out how to do it, when I'm saving answers to session variable to not lost them I have to counters, counter1 in wich I have the number of questions in that page and counter2 that I fill it with `counter2 + 1` when I'm saving the answer if it is not null, I had forgotten that I had that, so I was basically checking it before, so I didn't have the need to make any javascript or something, thanks anyway